# Unable to extract strings to strings.xml

Tags: android

hiho
could someone tell me, how i should extract these strings? anything crashes the app.

```
private String lv_arr[] = {

        "Weitere FAQs vom Autor dieser App",
        "Welche Wasserwerte sollte ich messen?",
        "Wie häufig sollte ich die Wasserwerte messen?"};
```

I tried:

```
private String lv_arr[] = {

        R.string.string_1,
        "Welche Wasserwerte sollte ich messen?",
        "Wie häufig sollte ich die Wasserwerte messen?"};
```

I tried:

```
private String lv_arr[] = {

        getString(R.string.string_1),
        "Welche Wasserwerte sollte ich messen?",
        "Wie häufig sollte ich die Wasserwerte messen?"};
```

I tried:

```
private String lv_arr[] = {

        ""+getText(R.string.string_1)+"",
        "Welche Wasserwerte sollte ich messen?",
        "Wie häufig sollte ich die Wasserwerte messen?"};
```

Nothing is working.
Crazy
Thanks for Help Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a string array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="string_array_name">
        <item>text_string</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: But there have to be a normal solution if i ant to add from resources without string array

Comment: @Alex these strings are in your resources :)

Comment: Yeah, you have to put that on a xml resource file. Load with String[] planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

Comment: Now i tried

    public class HowTo extends Activity {
 
 Resources res = getResources();
 ListView listFAQ;
 private String[] lv_arr = res.getStringArray(R.array.faq_title_array);
 
 
But this doesn't work....
I hate android

Answer (score 0):

To use getString(int) you have to use it from an instance of the Context class. The Context class is the super-class of both Activity and Service. So **make sure the class from which you are calling the getString(R.string.string_1) command is inside an activity that extends an Activity or a Service (basically any child of Context or Context itself)**.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
public class ... extends Activity {
    private String lv_arr[];

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        lvArr = new String[] {
            getString(R.string.string_1),
            getString(R.string.string_2),
            getString(R.string.string_3), // etc
        };
    }
}
```